# Xamarin.Android (BiometricPrompt): setAllowedAuthenticators() method missing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, androidx, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I've implemented BiometricPrompt for biometric login using the [Nuget package published by Microsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Biometric/1.0.1.2) successfully.

I want my app to only allow strong (Class 3) biometric hardware. The native documentation states I should call [setAllowedAuthenticators()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder#setAllowedAuthenticators(int)) passing in [BIOMETRIC_STRONG](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricManager.Authenticators#BIOMETRIC_STRONG) as the flag. However, I'm unable to find this method the PromptInfo builder class. My builder code looks like this at the moment.

```
  var builder = new BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                    .SetTitle(Alerts.AndroidFingerPrintDialog_SignIn)
                    .SetDescription(Alerts.AndroidFingerPrintDialog_FingerPrintPrompt)
                    .SetConfirmationRequired(false);
```

Where is the method defined in the Nuget package (or is it not supported at all)?

Answer (score 1):

`setAllowedAuthenticators` was added in **API level 30**.

So you would need to use Xamarin.Android 11.0 and above as the compile target for your application in order to have access to that function.

> August 5, 2020 — Xamarin.Android 11.0.0.3

- This version is included in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.7 and Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.7.

re: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/release-notes/11/11.0

Note: You will need to use [Runtime checks for Android versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/android-api-levels?tabs=windows#runtime-checks-for-android-versions) to call the correct `BiometricPrompt.Builder` functions for different APIs